# I'm trying to have a message pop up for if an invalid menu item is chosen multiple times

Tags: java, eclipse, menu

The goal is if the user puts an invalid option in three times, the program will tell the user to try again later and end the program. The code I have is below, I hope this makes sense, I am sorry if it doesn't. If you have any questions please let me know. I've also never asked a question here before so it may not be uploaded correctly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, total = 0, option = 0, ex; // Creates integer variables
    do {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\tBasic Math Calculator");// Title
        System.out.println("\t---------------------");
        System.out.println("\tEnter your choice from the following menu:");
        System.out.println("\t------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("1.\tAddition");// All the menu options
        System.out.println("2.\tSubtraction");
        System.out.println("3.\tMultiplication");
        System.out.println("4.\tDivision");
        System.out.println("5.\tGenerate Random number");
        System.out.println("6.\tQuit");

        boolean valid;
        do {
            valid = true;
            try {
                option = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());// Stores the users answers
                if (option < 1 || option > 6) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
                    valid = false;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
                valid = false;
            }
        } while (!valid);

        switch (option) {// The math and titles for every option
        case 1:
            System.out.println("You chose to add two numbers: ");
            System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
            num1 = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
            num2 = sc.nextInt();
            total = num1 + num2;
            System.out.println("The two numbers you chose added together is " + total);
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("You chose to subtract two numbers: ");
            System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
            num1 = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
            num2 = sc.nextInt();
            total = num1 - num2;
            System.out.println("The two numbers you chose subtracted together is " + total);
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("You chose to multiply two numbers: ");
            System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
            num1 = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
            num2 = sc.nextInt();
            total = num1 * num2;
            System.out.println("The two numbers you chose multiplied together is " + total);
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("You chose to divide two numbers: ");
            System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
            num1 = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
            num2 = sc.nextInt();
            total = num1 / num2;
            if (num2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("You can't divide by 0");
            } else {
                System.out.println("The two numbers you chose divided together is " + total + "with a quotient of "
                        + (num1 % num2));
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("You chose to get two random numbers: ");
            System.out.println("Enter your lower limit:");
            num1 = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter your upper limit:");
            num2 = sc.nextInt();
            total = num1 + num2;
            Random rand = new Random();
            int rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(num1 + num2);
            System.out.println("The random intigers is: " + rand_int1);
            break;
        case 6:// If the user wants to quit
            ex = 2;
            break;
        default:// Tells their option was incorrect
            System.out.println("Invalid choice, choice " + option + " was not an option");

        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue?1.Yes 2.No");// Asks the user if they want to proceed
        ex = sc.nextInt(); // A thank you message for the user for running the program
    } while (ex == 1);
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Thank you for using the basic calculator!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it, I realize they are different but I didn't know if broadening the comments would help I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No, deliberate mistagging like that is usually the easiest way to attract downvotes, eventually resulting in a question ban

Comment: Ah okay, I'm sorry, I haven't ever asked a question on here before, thank you for the advice though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65780875/how-do-i-create-a-java-function-that-scans-user-input-and-returns-the-datatype-i/65781325#65781325 . Always google or check stackoverflow for these type of questions before posting them

Comment: Try using a count variable alongwith valid variable. if count<=3 then it must as otherwise it should end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by creating a nested loop before the start if `switch` statement:

```
//...

System.out.println("6.\tQuit");

boolean valid;
do {
    valid = true;
    try {
        option = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());// Stores the users answers
        if (option < 1 || option > 6) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
            valid = false;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
        valid = false;
    }
} while (!valid);

switch (option) {// The math and titles for every option

//...
```

**A sample run after this change:**

```
    Basic Math Calculator
    ---------------------
    Enter your choice from the following menu:
    ------------------------------------------
1.  Addition
2.  Subtraction
3.  Multiplication
4.  Division
5.  Generate Random number
6.  Quit
a
Invalid input. Please try again.
9
Invalid input. Please try again.
4
You chose to divide two numbers: 
Enter your first number:
```

Check the full code at [ideone](https://ideone.com/cpbohN).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the `valid` and `do-while`  for checking times of  invalid input

If you want to quit the program after 3 invalid option entered by user , you have to increment the count of `ex` and change the condition at `while`  loop.

Initialize `ex=1`

Change case 6 and default as below

```
case 6:// If the user wants to quit
            System.exit(0);
            break;
default:
         ex = ex+1;
         break;
```

and

while condition as below

```
while (ex <4);  //
```

Following is the full code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, total = 0, ex= 1; // Creates integer variables
    do {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\tBasic Math Calculator");// Title
        System.out.println("\t---------------------");
        System.out.println("\tEnter your choice from the following menu:");
        System.out.println("\t------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("1.\tAddition");// All the menu options
        System.out.println("2.\tSubtraction");
        System.out.println("3.\tMultiplication");
        System.out.println("4.\tDivision");
        System.out.println("5.\tGenerate Random number");
        System.out.println("6.\tQuit");



       switch (option) {// The math and titles for every option
        case 1:
            System.out.println("You chose to add two numbers: ");
            System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
            num1 = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
            num2 = sc.nextInt();
            total = num1 + num2;
            System.out.println("The two numbers you chose added together is " + total);
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("You chose to subtract two numbers: ");
            System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
            num1 = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
            num2 = sc.nextInt();
            total = num1 - num2;
            System.out.println("The two numbers you chose subtracted together is " + total);
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("You chose to multiply two numbers: ");
            System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
            num1 = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
            num2 = sc.nextInt();
            total = num1 * num2;
            System.out.println("The two numbers you chose multiplied together is " + total);
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("You chose to divide two numbers: ");
            System.out.println("Enter your first number:");
            num1 = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter your second number:");
            num2 = sc.nextInt();
            total = num1 / num2;
            if (num2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("You can't divide by 0");
            } else {
                System.out.println("The two numbers you chose divided together is " + total + "with a quotient of "
                        + (num1 % num2));
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("You chose to get two random numbers: ");
            System.out.println("Enter your lower limit:");
            num1 = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter your upper limit:");
            num2 = sc.nextInt();
            total = num1 + num2;
            Random rand = new Random();
            int rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(num1 + num2);
            System.out.println("The random intigers is: " + rand_int1);
            break;
        case 6:// If the user wants to quit
            System.out.println("Thank you for using the basic calculator!");            
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        default:// Tells their option was incorrect
            ex=ex+1;
            System.out.println("Invalid choice, choice " + option + " was not an option");

        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue?1.Yes 2.No");// Asks the user if they want to proceed
        //ex = sc.nextInt(); // A thank you message for the user for running the program
    } while (ex<4);
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Thank you for using the basic calculator!");
}
```

**Edited**
Below is the sample output

```
    Basic Math Calculator
    ---------------------
    Enter your choice from the following menu:
    ------------------------------------------
1.  Addition
2.  Subtraction
3.  Multiplication
4.  Division
5.  Generate Random number
6.  Quit
7
Invalid choice, choice 7 was not an option
Please try again
    Basic Math Calculator
    ---------------------
    Enter your choice from the following menu:
    ------------------------------------------
1.  Addition
2.  Subtraction
3.  Multiplication
4.  Division
5.  Generate Random number
6.  Quit
7
Invalid choice, choice 7 was not an option
Please try again
    Basic Math Calculator
    ---------------------
    Enter your choice from the following menu:
    ------------------------------------------
1.  Addition
2.  Subtraction
3.  Multiplication
4.  Division
5.  Generate Random number
6.  Quit
7
Invalid choice, choice 7 was not an option
Please try again
-----------------------------------------
Thank you for using the basic calculator!
```

Comment: I used this and it seemed to have worked, but for some reason, my ex integer won't go above two. I added a System.out.println(ex); under the "do you want to continue" to track the ex value and it wouldn't surpass 2 for some reason. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: Please see my edit . It is working fine for me

Comment: Are you still having ```ex=sc.nextInt();``` , because I have commented it .

Comment: Okay, I found out what it was, you were right. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: If this was helpful , please upvote my answer